# serialized JSON cast as a string as a payload for a http Request/Rest API?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

When using the Humanity/Shiftplanning API, the payload has to be structured like this (Python example):

```
def get_json(skill,date):
url = "https://www.humanity.com/api/"
payload = """data={
    "token": "%s",
    "request": {
    "module":"schedule.shifts",
    "method": "GET",
    "start_date":"%s",
        "end_date":"%s",
        "mode":"overview",
        "filter_by_skill": "%s",
        "vacation": "0"
    }
}"""%(token,date,date,skill)
```

I  do not understand is the """data={...}""" part. What is the advantage/reason of/for "assigning the JSON to a variable" inside a string? I am aware of the fact that it is just the string, not actually a variable. I also assume that is then formatted "correctly" on the receiving end. I just don't understand why it is not just the JSON.

Thank you for assisting me in understanding.

CODE UPDATE EDIT:

```
payload = "data="+json.dumps({
            "token": "{}".format(token),
            "request": {
            "module":"staff.employees",
            "method":"GET"              

            }
        })
headers = {'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Where is the code that sends this? Does it have a `json.loads(...)`? Usually a programmer will just use a `dict` instead of a `str` but I assume this programmer did not know you can put variables in a `dict` when you create it, so they used a string and string formatting via `%`.

Comment: I added the code that sends the payload and another snippet that shows the construction of the payload with the json.dumps() method and different string formatting via .format()
However, I still have to create the string containing the word "data" and then add the JSON, the JSON itself would not suffice.

Comment: You dont need `"{}".format(token),` Just do `token,` if `token` is a `str`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, that doesn't really answer my main question.

Comment: Sorry I was addressing your update. Is your question still why they use a string? Your updated code doesn't even use a string.

Comment: I am assigning the `str "data"` `+` the `json.dumps()` to the variable `"payload"`. Hence the type of `"payload"` is `str`.
It seems quite unnecessary to me. I don't know a lot about how APIs function, so I am curious if there is any logical reason to force this style.

Comment: To elaborate, the data= is what I don't get. Why would you have what looks like a variable assignment inside a string?

Comment: That code works with the `data=`? It looks like that is a typo in your updated code.

Comment: It is the format that is required for using the API. Thanks for the comment, it seems that this is not really common, hence my question.